# SPI transaction weird behavior

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, python

Im completely new to this topic so excuse any mistakes I make. I have a MMC5983MA sensor which works well with I2C. However Im having trouble with the SPI protocol. I have all wired up and im trying to do a simple transaction with the function xfer2() from the spidev library to get the ID of the sensor. However I don’t get any respone when all is setup up.

The weird thing is that by accident I discovered that when all wires are connected except SCL, in the exact moment I connect SCL I get the correct response from the sensor but only once (or rather everytime I diconnect and connect).

Below is the code I’m using:

```
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 25000

while True:
  id = spi.xfer2([0xEF,0x00])
  time.sleep(0.01)         
  
  print(id)
  time.sleep(1)
```

I also looked at it with piscope but that didnt help me much. Below I'll add two screenshots where the first one is with correct response and the second one where I get nothing.

[image: With Response]

[image: Wihtout Response]

Any help would be highly appreciated

Update:

I reduced the frequency and checked piscope again and now SCL looks different. See below:
[image]

Update 2:
Fixed it. Turns out it was the glitch on the chip select at the end.
I changed it to a GPIO port and manually pulled it low and high and now it works perfectly. Thanks for your help

Comment: The CLK signal makes no sense at all. Is that really what it's like or is the measurement wrong? It'll never work with that so called clock.

Comment: I dont know for sure. I dont have access to a physical oscilloscope so i just used piscope and assumed its correct.

Comment: What is the Picscope threshold value to trigger 1 and 0s ?
According to this https://www.picotech.com/support/viewtopic.php?t=37211 you should do a SPI channel and it should auto set values

Comment: Try setting a lower clock speed. In case the Piscope is too slow to correctly read the clock signal, that should fix it. Maybe it even solves the main issue, if it is due to too improper wiring or similar.

Comment: @Mat I think they're using a [piscope](https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html), not a [Picoscope](https://www.picotech.com/products/oscilloscope). At first I was confused as well.

Comment: @Seir oh ok my bad but maybe there is some kind of threshold values ?

Comment: @Mat (a) either that, or (b) the piscope sample rate is too low, or (c) the actual signal is erroneous

Comment: @Seir  I updated the post

Comment: So it seems like the piscope sampling rate was the problem. Now it actually looks like `0xEF 0x00` is being transmitted, while MISO shows `0x00 0x00`. The glitch on the CE0 signal I don't like particularly.

Answer (score 2):

SPI has [four modes of operation](https://www.mikroe.com/blog/spi-bus) and I think you may be using the wrong one.

From the [sensor datasheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/821/Memsic_09102019_MMC5983MA_Datasheet_Rev_A-1635338.pdf), the clock idles high and the data is sampled on the rising edge:

[image]

This would be SPI mode 3. Try this (I've never used SPI from Python, so I'm guessing here):

```
spi.max_speed_hz = 25000
spi.mode = 3
```

By connecting the clock mid-way you may be simulating a clock that idles high and enabling a single frame to be read correctly by the sensor.

Comment: Tried all four modes. Got no response with any of them however the signal chart of mode 3 does look the most like in the datasheet. Interesting is also that in mode 1,2,3 I dont get anything back even when I disconnect and connect

Comment: @FlipFlop What does picoscope show for mode 3?

Comment: See the update i posted in the original post. Thanks for your help :).